# Why is my form inputs not resetting after submit?

Tags: reactjs

Hello my form submits the info correctly but is not resetting all of the input fields for some reason. Please assist. The 3 inputs in my form are Name, Location, and Review. The Review is the only field that resets after submit. please assist.

**My code:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) {
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/Reviews") // 3 - GET updated reviews with last post
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((reviews) => setallReviews(reviews));

      fetch("http://localhost:3000/Description")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((descriptions) => setDescriptions(descriptions));

      setLoading(false); 
    }
  }, [loading]); 

 
 

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const aReview = { nameInput, trailInput, reviewInput };

    fetch("http://localhost:3000/Reviews", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(aReview),
    }) 
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((aReview) => {
        setReview("");
        setTrail(descriptions.nameInput[0]);   //issue here descriptions doesnt have nameInput in it??
        setName("");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error: ", error);
      });
    setLoading(true); 
  };

const options = [
  "Burke Lake Park",
  "Lake Accotink Park",
  "Armistead Park",
  "Cherrydale Park",
  "W & OD Trail"
]
```

**how I set up my form:**

```
const Form = ({
  nameInput,
  trailInput,
  reviewInput,
  setName,
  setTrail,
  setReview,
  options,
  handleSubmit
}) => {

  return (
    
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      className="w-50 p-5 border border-secondary rounded"
    >
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          value={nameInput}
          placeholder="Name"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          required 
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Location</label>
        <select
          className="form-control"
          value={trailInput}
          onChange={(e) => setTrail(e.target.value)}
        >
          {options.map((o, idx) => (
            <option key={idx}>{o}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Review</label>
        <textarea
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Write a review!"
          rows="3"
          type="text"
          value={reviewInput}
          onChange={(e) => setReview(e.target.value)}
          required  
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-4">
        Submit
      </button>

    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

the Review input resets correctly but the Name doesn't neither the Location input. Thx.

Comment: Unrelated, but the “loading” state update in the effect update will occur some time before the fetches complete; this may not have been your intent.

Comment: It’s not clear where any of these properties live, how they’re used, whether they’re state or props, etc.

Comment: It's on my github if you'd like more context?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `e.preventDefault()`, which basically prevents, that the default action of the event (in this case `e`) "executes".

Find more information about it on the [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

> The `preventDefault()` method of the `Event` interface tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

For the submit event, that default action is reloading the page. Removing the line should solve your problem.

Comment: Reloading an SPA is generally not the right approach since you lose context unless set up to rehydrate somehow.

Comment: I removed the preventdefault and my page won't load at all now..